# What sorting algorithm is this? ("merge iterator with itself")

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, merge

As long as the list isn't sorted, keep replacing it with a merge of an iterator with itself. Is that (equivalent to) one of the commonly known sorting algorithms, just implemented weirdly, or is it something new?

```py
from random import shuffle
from heapq import merge
from itertools import pairwise

# Create test data
a = list(range(100))
shuffle(a)

# Sort
while any(x > y for x, y in pairwise(a)):
    it = iter(a)
    a = list(merge(it, it))

print(a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PZAxDsIwDEX3nMISSyqBBBtCgoUjcAJLONRSmwTHFfQsLCxwJy7BGXChxYstf-c_O7dn7rVO8X5_dBoW69c7SGpBMB4tcZuTKJS6C6Eh95VqwnyelJbkNPZZSTSlpkxaRpYLF3JuBnshVAKlonBERYewhYaLeiOdyK-Wy6pyI8djNbw5mIm71NwQYOz9FXbQQ0gC17kVHP8Am682DixYzXZYZLAYGn_Md1HPOjfZSC4LR7Wp39Xj8dMnfAA)

`heapq.merge` does merge two inputs in the "standard" way, but it's an implementation detail and its inputs are supposed to be sorted, which they aren't here (and they're also not independent, as they use the same source). To eliminate it being an implementation detail, let `merge` actually be this (the standard way, always comparing the two "current" values, yielding the smaller one and fetching a replacement for it):

```
def merge(xs, ys):
    none = object()
    x = next(xs, none)
    y = next(ys, none)
    while (x is not none) and (y is not none):
        if x <= y:
            yield x
            x = next(xs, none)
        else:
            yield y
            y = next(ys, none)
    if x is not none:
        yield x
    if y is not none:
        yield y
    yield from xs
    yield from ys
```

Comment: An inefficient one...

Comment: I suspect this is similar to bubble sort, with `merge` causing small items to bubble down towards the start of the list.

Comment: (I'm not positive, but I don't think I'd assume that `list(it) == merge(it, it)` implies the list is sorted for all possible iterators without a proof.)

Comment: @chepner Not sure what you mean, can you rephrase? The way you wrote it, that equation is only true for the empty list.

Comment: @chepner Even assuming you mean a separate `it` for the LHS and RHS, this is trivially not true for iterables where elements have dynamic, random ordering. You can randomly hit `list(it1) == merge(it2, it2)` in one iteration by sheer luck but then get a different ordering in the next as the RNG changes its sequence.

Comment: Well, yes, but even without that, I'd need to see a proof that `x = list(merge(it, it))` is either sorted or has a different order than `a` originally had before I'd assume this sorts any list in the first place.

Comment: (`merge` promises that `merge(x, y)` is sorted if `x` and `y` were both sorted. I don't know what happens if `x` and `y` *aren't* sorted, except that it's probably implementation-dependent.)

Comment: @chepner Ooh, that about the promise precondition is an excellent point. Maybe I should implement `merge` myself (or at least say something like "Assume `merge` works like ...", describing how it does work).

Comment: @chepner I added an explicit standard `merge` implementation to avoid the implementation-dependence on `heapq.merge`. I hope that fixes the issue?

Comment: @chepner The proof chiefly depends on whether you look at the implementation or specification. The spec leaves it up to the implementation what happens for unsorted inputs. In CPython, `merge` always emits the lowest element from all the popped heads of all its iterators - meaning that feeding it an iterator n times performs a n-item window sort. All implementations known to me have this behaviour as well.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The second half of your last comment sounds like a good way of thinking about it. I think that (maybe with 2 instead of n) would be good in your answer.

Comment: I think the idea of what `merge` actually does came to me because I was trying to decide if this was more like bubble sort or more like selection sort. (I pretty quickly settled on the former, but the question of whether this terminated at all stuck.)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I meant putting it in terms of a two-item window and what happens with it. That can nicely be seen in both algorithms, showing how they're equivalent. I updated my answer with how I imagined it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed bubble sort implemented weirdly.

Bubble sort repeatedly does this until the list is sorted:

- Slide a two-item window over the list. At each position, sort the two items in the window, then slide the window one position to the right. This leaves the smaller item behind, the larger item remains in the window, and the next item enters the window.

The `merge` with the same iterator twice does effectively the same thing. Its "two-item window" is the two "current values", the `x` and `y` in the question's `merge` implementation. Like in bubble sort, the smaller one is "left behind" (gets yielded, becomes the next item in the output). The larger one remains in the "window" (remains `x` or `y`). And the next item from the input list enters the window (becomes the other one of `x` and `y`).

Thinking of Knuth's *"[Beware ... I have only proved it ... not tried it](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/faq.html)"*, let's also try it, checking experimentally whether the behavior is indeed identical to ordinary bubble sort. Sorting a shuffled list with 1000 elements both with my question's sort and with bubble sort, and recording the state of the list after each "round". They're identical for both sorts.

```py
from random import shuffle
from heapq import merge
from itertools import pairwise

# Create test data
a = list(range(1000))
shuffle(a)

def mysort_steps(a):
    steps = []
    while any(x > y for x, y in pairwise(a)):
        it = iter(a)
        a = list(merge(it, it))
        steps.append(a[:])
    return steps

def bubblesort_steps(a):
    steps = []
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n - 1):
        swapped = False
        for j in range(n - 1 - i):
            if a[j] > a[j+1]:
                a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j]
                swapped = True
        if not swapped:
            break
        steps.append(a[:])
    return steps

print(mysort_steps(a[:]) == bubblesort_steps(a[:]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVJLasMwEIUudYqBbmyalGRXAumm0BN0F0yR8ThWYsuqNCbxWbrJpj1FT9LTdCRb-bSFUoGRNG-e3pvxvL6bnqpWHw5vHZXTu8-rj9K2DVipC95UY1pL4KquLGsUAapQmpeINGjXY1wRWmrb2kXMSGV3yqEQ1_BgURICoSMoJEkhYQm1cpSw0hqT-Ww2S1MxCiUyFaLAEpre8UvPjtA4Di4E8Ao3pq-ycN1VqkaQuk_2cA89lK2F_YQPSh8tMHck-6WI2d6u14nBo6FQUqJowinpCQ-qt9IY1EUiV4tsgCxSZ_WADp7zLs9r_Nu39oKoowdvW3nPQ0M0TGF-5tntvHTBnEdZc09j3NM232j8qTNqKLkEudpk3CDebubZJRrqZ3gyoqwyHEIg-5F7MvNku5MXFtEtRfRSIucB2P6vmcYqzb_jYgR8KiyXvzTZI-kwxOMsx5n-Ag)

Answer (score 3):

This is a convoluted way of writing bubblesort.

`merge(it, it)` means sorting all pairs as `it[0]` against `it[1]`, then the pair of the larger of that against `it[2]` and so on.

- The "`it[0]` against `it[1]` against `it[2]` …" part comes from double-iterating the same iterator, which forces each step to fetch the next element regardless of which "end" is iterated.
- The pairwise sort comes directly from what `merge` does, which looks at the head of each iterator and emits the smaller one while keeping the larger one for the next step.

`any(x > y for x, y in pairwise(a))` tests for sorted'ness, i.e. if the next iteration would perform any swaps to ensure pairwise sorting.

[This is practically a textbook definition of bubblesort:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

> Bubble sort, sometimes referred to as sinking sort, is a simple sorting algorithm that **repeatedly steps through the input list element by element, comparing the current element with the one after it, swapping their values if needed. These passes through the list are repeated until no swaps have to be performed during a pass**, meaning that the list has become fully sorted.

Note that the "current element" in bubblesort is next position but the  larger element of the previous pair. This is because the swap is performed before the next pairwise comparison.

Comment: What if `it[0]` is the larger one and then gets compared to `it[2]`? That doesn't fit the *"comparing the current element with the one after it"* from the bubble sort definition.

Comment: @nocomment "the current element" is the larger of the previous pair. Bubblesort swaps immediately *and before the next comparison*, meaning a larger element bubbles through *as the current element* until it hits a larger element (which then becomes the new current element in the next step).

Answer (score 1):

No. it's not equivalent to any commonly known sorting algorithm, however some may see similarities to bubble sort. It's more of a curiosity and an interesting use of Python's standard library functions rather than a practical sorting method. Something to show off and confuse your fellow team members ;)

What might be counterintuitive at the first look is the iterator merge step. The `heapq.merge()` expects two (or more) sorted inputs from which it returns a single sorted data set. But we use the same iterator, so each time `merge()` requests the next item from either input, it in fact advances the same iterator. This means that the first request for an item pulls the first element, and the immediate next request (which would conceptually be from the "other" sorted list if they were distinct) also tries to pull the next item from the same sequence.

The "sorting" effect in this case is more a byproduct of repeatedly interleaving and checking for sortedness until the list happens to be sorted. That's also the reason why merging iterator more times than 2 times (i.e. `merge(it, it, it)` would increase the complexity of how elements are interleaved, potentially leading to more iterations needed before the list becomes sorted, slowing down the whole process instead of speeding it up.

Comment: Have a look at my answer's experiment, it does seem to behave exactly like bubble sort.

Comment: And the number of iterations seems to **decrease** with merging 3 or more of `it`: [Demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZFLasQwDIbp1qcQzMYeMiXpqgy0mx4jhGKIPDHEj8oKk5ylm9m0h-pp6rymUG9s6fevT0Kf33HiLvjb7Wtgc3r-eRgNBQekfZsv62IghtQNxvQoFqlDHT92xSFdtrxlJA6hT7sWtaWrTSjEAd4INSMwJoZWsxYaXqC3iWUmXVBWZVkqJTaQ1EqIFg24KeVK74kxppw8C8hnibK9bpbw2tkeQftJjvAKE5hAMBb5Yf29hezdzPOxnN1zuzNnT94bWkaSx9pyA0dw6u_LAn7UMaJvpa7PzSoR8kB-VYWY8W5mr4M9FVBVGzuS9bl-AT16-W80pdYFbHvY9_EL).

Comment: I am not sure what your experiment was about to prove. By the way `merge()` works, it must internally swap fetched elements if they are not in order. So yes, that's what you do in bubble sort but the code from your question is more of an iterative process that eventually leads to a sorted list rather than a deliberate sorting strategy.

Comment: My experiment shows that after each iteration (of the "outer loop"), the list is exactly the same in both algorithms.

Comment: No, it's just special case because you used only two "inputs" for `merge()`. Again, use more and it won't be.

Comment: The question isn't about a version with more than two. It's about the code shown in the question.

Comment: Then yes, it acts like bubble sort.